# Laravel 5.7 Auth::attempt return false

Tags: authentication, laravel-5.7

Auth::attempt always return false , can't understand why .

> web.php

```
Route::post('/login','SessionsController@store');
Route::post('/register','RegisterController@store');
```

> RegisterController.php

```
public function store()
{
    $this->validate(\request(),[
        'name' => 'bail|required|min:3|max:30|string',
        'email' => 'bail|required|email',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed'

    ]);
    $user = User::create(request(['name','email','password']));
    $user->fill([
        'password' => Hash::make(\request()->newPassword)
    ])->save();
    auth()->login($user);
    return redirect()->home();
}
```

> SessionsController.php

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    if (! Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        return back()->withErrors(['message'=>'Email and Password doesn\'t match']);

    }
    return redirect()->home();
}
```

> create.blade.php (Login Page)

```
<form action="/login" method="post">
            @csrf
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email" class="form-text">Email :</label>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" required>
            </div>
           <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password" class="form-text" >Password :</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" required>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right" value="Register">
        </form>
```

Every thing is okay with registration and database , passwords is hashed .
Auth::attempt always return false .
Can't understand why , posted it after few hours of searching .. most of code is just copied from documentation.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you get for `dd($credentials)` ?

Comment: @IjasAmeenudeen same data i submitted.

Comment: solved , Thanks for you help , really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

just changing

```
$user = User::create(request(['name','email','password']));
$user->fill([
    'password' => Hash::make(\request()->newPassword)
])->save();
```

to

```
 $user = User::create([
        'name' => request('name'),
        'email' => request('email'),
        'password' => bcrypt(request('password'))
    ]);
```